# Zend Framework 2 load class PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to load a class that has an underscore in it in ZF2.

This is the project I want to use: https://github.com/PHPGangsta/GoogleAuthenticator

The folder paths look like this:

```
/module
  /Application
      /Service
          /MyService.php
/vendor/
  /PHPGangsta
      /GoogleAuthenticator.php
```

`GoogleAuthenticator.php` has a class named `PHPGangsta_GoogleAuthenticator` which I want to use in `MyService.php`, without having to `require` any files.

Also, I cannot change files inside `PHPGangsta`, because the project is submoduled under git.

Can you help configure zf2 class autoload?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you installed ZF2 using Composer (which is the recommended method), edit your `composer.json` to add `phpgangsta/googleauthenticator`  to the require section. Then run `composer install`. That's it. You should then be able to use the library in your application - you don't need to do any additional autoload configuration.

Comment: I don't have access to composer. The whole application is under git. So submodules are my only way of adding new components.

Comment: What do you mean by "you don't have access"? You can still install it, can't you?

Comment: I mean that I can do that locally, but not on deployment machines. And on those, composer will not be installed.